# Filter for array type of field in loopback

Tags: arrays, filter, where-clause, loopback

I am using loopback v3 with mongodb database and implementing filter for array type of field.
inq operator is not working.

I have an array of object like below

```
[ 
  {
    "name":"name1",
    "title": "title1",
    "category": ["a", "b","c"]
  },

  {
    "name":"name2",
    "title": "title2",
    "category": ["x", "y","z"]
  },

  {
    "name":"name3",
    "title": "title3",
    "category": ["b", "d","e"]
  }

]
```

**now  i want a list where category containing "b"**

So i am using below filter method

```
filter: {where:{category:{inq:["b"]}}}
```

I think **inq** does n't work for this case.it gives empty response.

**Output : [ ]**

how can i get my desired output.

Desired output:

```
[ 
  {
    "name":"name1",
    "title": "title1",
    "category": ["a", "b","c"]
  },

  {
    "name":"name3",
    "title": "title3",
    "category": ["b", "d","e"]
  }

]
```

below is my properties

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "category": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for me the above scenario works fine. Although in your code the array closing brackets should be `]` instead of `}`, just pointing out something I found in your code.

How did you setup your model for this?

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "category": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Does your model properties look like this ?

Comment: Yeah , My model property looks like this . and  braces was typo

Comment: can you post your model properties?

Comment: Here it is my model properties.                                                     
 "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "image_url": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "slug": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },

Comment: where is the `category` property in this, that you mentioned? In your given properties there is no `Array of string type`

Comment: It is same as you mentioned .. here is my properties                                 "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "category": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },

Comment: Hi itsajan , if you check this url , you will find that inq doesn't work for multiple value of array filed.  https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#inq  .. my case is different from this given example of this url

Comment: hi @itssajan , It's done ,i have used "in" instead of "inq" .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
"role": {
  "type": "array",
  "default": [
    "patient"
  ]
}
```

let filter = {role:{in:['doctor']}}

```
    this.find({
        where: filter
    }, cb);
```